# Почему transform: translate перестает работать?

Tags: html, css, transform

У меня есть блок, который я передвигаю на 50% от ширины и высоты самого блока по `x, y` с помощью `transform: translate`. Все работает, но когда я прописываю этому же блоку `transform: scale` этот блок меняет свое расположение и передвигается в верхний левый угол. Что происходит? Почему свойство transform: translate перестает работать?

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: потому что вы перезаписываете свойство transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать `translate` и `scale` в `transform`, пишите так:

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Hello!</div>
```